# Can anyone explain Angular JS Animation Types

Tags: angularjs, animation

At the home page

http://www.nganimate.org/

there is a table, where, on the first column, goes all angular directives, which support animations. And on the second column, there is a list of supported animation types for each directive. Everything is fine, except I have no idea, what are those Animation Types exactly mean. I couldn't find anything about it neither at http://docs.angular.org or at http://nganimate.org. Perhaps it is some common web pages animation terminology? AngularJS documentation was always so consistent and comprehensive, but this point has been missed somehow. I was searching for it, until got driven nuts :-( Can anyone explain, or provide a link to a strict explanation of those 5 Animation Types: enter, leave, move, show and hide ?

Comment: Note that the nganimate.org info is obsolete. You should refer to the info on docs.angular.org.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice your comment, I'm a newbie on StackOverflow and didn't get used to what areas to pay the most attention. Ok, I will keep that in mind, by the way I've sorted out that animation types, but can not explain it here because an explanation would be rather large, involving other aspects, for example, the notion, that angular animations without directives, become pointless, because each directive type defines, which animation event to fire and when.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I just had to read https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations#how-they-work and there is a "passive" explanation of those Animation Types. I was confused because I expected some separate article or section, explaining them item-by-item. But reading this one carefuly will give a clear understanding of what are those Animation Types.